# how can i restore database mysql with batch file

Tags: batch-file

i want to restore .SQL file by batch file but it does't work

```
    "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin" -u root --password=password  \. C:/file.SQL
```

Comment: Plesae provide more informations. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect input file using < operator.

Try this command inside your batch file:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe -u root --password=password < C:\file.SQL
```

Comment: it show like this "warning using a password on the command line interface can be insecure"

Comment: try to use `mysql_config_editor` to set up a "login path".

Comment: it show like this "mysql error 1045 (28000): access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: no)"

Comment: how are you running the command now ? did you already executed mysql_config_editor ?

Comment: yes i try put password in there but it just change from (using password: no) to be (using password: yes)